# Contract calling convention for sum type

Tags: michelson

burn function in KT_token contract can be called with arg format:

```
burn: (pair (or (unit %uSD) (unit %xTZ)) mutez)
```

so I tried,

```
./tezos-client transfer 0 from alice to KT_token --entrypoint burn --arg '(Pair %XTZ 100000)' --burn-cap 1

./tezos-client transfer 0 from alice to KT_token --entrypoint burn --arg '(Pair (unit %xTZ) 100000)' --burn-cap 1
```

it seems the type option can not accept both of the above format.  My question is, what is the correct argument to call this function?  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the [or](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#type-or) type, you must specify whether you're referring to the "left" (here `unit %uSD`) using the `Left` constructor or the "right" type (here `unit %xTZ`) using the `Right` constructor.
- The value of the type [unit](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com/#type-unit) is written `Unit`
- Michelson values does not have annotations, you should remove `%xTZ/%uSD` from your arg.

In you case, you get either:

```
--arg '(Pair (Left Unit) 100000)'
```

or

```
--arg '(Pair (Right Unit)) 100000)'
```

You can verify that these parameters are well-typed using `tezos-client`:

```
$ tezos.client -mode mockup typecheck data '(Pair (Left Unit) 100000)' \
      against type '(pair (or (unit %uSD) (unit %xTZ)) mutez)
```

Here I use [mockup mode](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/mockup.html) to avoid running a node.